# Graphviz, placing a graph in a subgraph alters x-coordinate of nodes

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create a graph that includes a cluster. When I create the cluster as its own graph, the layout makes sense, but when it is part of a cluster, two of the nodes switch places, increasing the total edge length.

Here is the code for the graph when it is not in a cluster.

```
digraph OrgChart {

edge[dir=none,color=black];
11->13;
12->13;
12->14;
13->15;
13->60;
13->61;
14->15;
{rank="same"; 11 12 14};
{rank="same"; 13 15};

}
```

This generates a graph that looks like this

[image: Test2]

When I make it part of a cluster with the following code

```
digraph OrgChart {

subgraph cluster{
edge[dir=none,color=black];
11->13;
12->13;
12->14;
13->15;
13->60;
13->61;
14->15;
{rank="same"; 11 12 14};
{rank="same"; 13 15};
}

}
```

which makes my graph look like this

[image: Test1]

I can't see any reason why 11 is between 12 and 14.

Why is this happening, and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One unsatisfying answer is to add this:

11->12 [style=invis];

That should put the 11 12 14 nodes back into their desired order.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that if I make it a regular subgraph and not a cluster, then it also fixes the problem.